# Vertically align text in navbar that includes a logo

Tags: html, css

The logo in my navbar is aligned left and the links in are aligned right but the links are sitting off center vertically within the navbar. No matter what I do I cannot get it to center. Thanks in advance for any help. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul>

        <a href = "index.html" class = "nav-logo"><img src="images/mo's_logo.png" title = "Go to Mo's Gyros Home" alt = "Mo's Gyros logo"></a>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Specials</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end of nav-wrapper -->
    </nav>
  </div> <!-- end of navbar-fixed -->
```

**CSS**

```
#nav-wrapper {
}

nav { 
        width: 100%;
        height: 38px;
        padding: 5px;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #5c5453;
}

.navbar-fixed {
        padding: 0;
}

.nav-logo {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 160px;
}

nav li { 
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-right: 50px;
}

a { 
        color: #8CBAD9;
        text-decoration: none; 
}

a:hover { 
        color: white;
        text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet, not just a CSS and HTML which we need to copy manually to check it out?

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/q7Lokzkx/)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have an anchor element, <a>, as a child of <ul>. Only <li> elements are allowed there.

Comment: Thank you potashin. I will do that from now on.

Comment: I dont quite understand how you want your layout to be is it something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q7Lokzkx/1/)

Comment: Antonio Smoljan, yes it look somewhat similar to that now but the logo is centered nicely, and the links are sitting near the top of the navbar and not centering vertically.

Comment: How big is your logo image?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q7Lokzkx/2/ Something like this?

Comment: are you wanting the links in on the right to display vertically?

Comment: kfreeman04208, no I want the links to display horizontally but center vertically.

Comment: makshh, i could not get that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/vb8yspjs/1/

Just change this in your CSS

```
ul {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 38px;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! That did it! I givea youa kiss!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to vertically center the text using JQuery:

```
//Get the DOM objects
w = $('.nav-wrapper');
wa = $('.nav-wrapper a');
wimg = $('.nav-wrapper a img');

//Set the nav wrapper to half its own height minus half of the link's text
w.css({
    'padding-top': (w.height() / 2) - (wa.height() / 2)
});

//Remove offset from image
wimg.css({
    'margin-top': -((w.height() / 2) - (wa.height() / 2))
});
```

Both the nav element and the nav-wrapper class need to be the same height, so you should set them both in one place:

```
.nav-wrapper, nav {
    height: 38px;
}
```

I also want to point out, the layout while viewing on a small screen breaks because the text starts wrapping. To fix this, I recommend checking out flexboxes. The only downside to those is that they are pretty new and still a bit buggy.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help but Nenad Vracar fixed this for me. I am in my first semester of web development and am not yet familiar with JQuery, only html5 and css3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, see if this works for what you are looking for. Just add it in your CSS

```
nav li { 
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 50px;
    position:relative;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: it works on firefox and IE what are you using to display page? all your wanting is for them to center in the middle of the div right?

Comment: I am using firefox and just tried it in IE and it's not working there either. Yes, just want to center vertically on right side.

Comment: I think you need to double check you code because it works here. https://jsfiddle.net/s27vk2sw/